# How to force pandas.io.parsers to set column-specific types

Tags: python, parsing, types, pandas, dataframe

today I am struggling with an interesting warnings:

```
parsers.py:1139: DtypeWarning: Columns (1,4) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
```

Let's start from the beginning, I have several files with thousands of lines each, the content of each file looks like this:

```
##ID    ChrA    StartA  EndA    ChrB    StartB  EndB    CnvType Orientation GeneA   StrandA LastExonA   TotalExonsA PhaseA  GeneB   StrandB LastExonB   TotalExonsB PhaseB  InFrame InPhase
nsv871164   1   8373207 8373207 1   8436802 8436802 DELETION    HT  ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   RERE    -   14  24  0   Not in Frame
dgv1n68 1   16765770    16765770    1   16936692    16936692    DELETION    HT  ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   NBPF1   -   2   29  -1  Not in Frame
nsv9213 1   16777016    16777016    1   16779533    16779533    DELETION    HT  NECAP2  +   6   8   0   NECAP2  +   6   8   1   In Frame    Not in Phase
.....
nsv510572   Y   16898737    16898737    Y   16904738    16904738    DELETION    HT  NLGN4Y  +   4   6   1   NLGN4Y  +   3   6   1   In Frame    In Phase
nsv10042    Y   59192042    59192042    Y   59196197    59196197    DELETION    HT  ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?
```

column[1] and column[4] refers to "Human Chromosomes" and are supposed to be 1 to 22 then X and Y.

Some files are short (2k lines) some are very long (200k lines).

If I make a pandas.Dataframe out of a short file, then no problem, the parser correctly recognizes the items in columns[1] and [4] as 'string'.

But if the file is long enough, the parser assigns 'int' until a certain point and then 'string' as soon it encounters 'X' or 'Y'.

At this point I got the warnings.

I think that is happening because the parser loads in memory a limited number of rows, then checks the best type to assign considering all the values of a column and then it goes on parsing the rest of the file.

Now, if all the rows can be parsed at once, then there are no mistakes, the parser recognizes all the values at once [1,2,3,4...,'X','Y'] and assign the best type (in this case 'str').
If the number of rows is too big, then the file is parsed in pieces and in my case the first piece contains only [1,2,3,4] and the parser assigns 'int'.

This, of course, is messing up my pipeline..

**How can I force the parser to assign ONLY to column[1] and [4] the type 'str'?**

This is the code I use to make Dataframes out of my files:

```
dataset = pandas.io.parsers.read_table(my_file, sep='\t', index_col=0)
```

Comment: If you know which columns have mixed types then you can pass a dict of the columns and desired dtype as a param to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) `dtype={'ChrA':'str',...}`

Comment: Great man! Thank you, it worked as I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the dtypes of the columns as a param to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) so if you know the columns then just pass a dict with column names as the key and dtype as the value, for example:

```
dataset = pandas.io.parsers.read_table(my_file, sep='\t', index_col=0, dtype={'ChrA':'str'})
```

Just keep adding additional column names to the dict.

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't clear how to specify dtype, I tried everything but the dictionary :)

Comment: The only problem is that it doesn't work if the engine type is python, otherwise it's sometimes useful to specify the dtypes upfront not just for cases like yours but also even if you have a large csv and the types are well defined numeric types as this will reduce the speed and memory usage as it doesn't need to guess the dtype